# Next button in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

how do i close my form after opening the next form (VB.net  Windows form)   like the Next button

I tried `Form2.show()` it shows form2 but does not close the form1 and if i type `me.close()`, the entire project stops

Answer (score 4):

If you just want `Form2` to be Visible you can hide `Form1` when you show `Form2`, then show it `Form1` again when you close `Form2`. What is happening is that once you close `Form1` your program will exit see below edit.

Something like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm2 As New Form2
    AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Form2Closing
    frm2.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub Form2Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Me.Show()
    RemoveHandler DirectCast(sender, Form2).FormClosed, AddressOf Form2Closing
End Sub
```

---

If you just are wanting to Close `Form1` and not go back to it once `Form2` is open, you can change your project settings from **When startup form closes**(which is the default) to **When last form closes** then you can close your first form without closing your application.

Comment: thank you,I got the source code!
I just needed to take My Project->Application->change shutdown mode to "When last form closes"
Niwayz thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what to close:

```
  Form1.Close()
```

Comment: thank you,I got the source code! I just needed to take My Project->Application->change shutdown mode to "When last form closes" Niwayz thank you for your help –

Answer (score 0):

You better **not** close your form after opening another one from it, unless you want that other one also closed. Otherwise it will cause ownership and visibility side effects, which you really don't want to deal with in the long run.

This is exactly why `me.close()` on your main form stops your project. You just have consider paradigms Microsoft put into a Winforms application. If you don't, you are guaranteed to get in trouble.

Instead, a wizard control is what you are probably looking for.